# installation of wifi in debian

Tags: debian, wifi, ifconfig, wlan, iwlwifi

```
~$ lspci -nn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller [8086:0104] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0126] (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller [0700]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family KT Controller [8086:1c3d] (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1c10] (rev b4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1c12] (rev b4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:1c16] (rev b4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 [8086:1c18] (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1c26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation QM67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller [8086:1c4f] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller [8086:1c03] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1c22] (rev 04)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0085] (rev 34)
0d:00.0 System peripheral [0880]: Ricoh Co Ltd PCIe SDXC/MMC Host Controller [1180:e823] (rev 07)
```

As [he was saying](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/645901/having-issue-with-debian-installation#comment1210259_645901). I was following [the Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi).

```
root@debian:/home/istiak# apt update && apt install firmware-iwlwifi
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package firmware-iwlwifi
root@debian:/home/istiak# modprobe -r iwlwifi ; modprobe iwlwifi
bash: modprobe: command not found
bash: modprobe: command not found
```

When I try to run `iwconfig` or `ifconfig` I get that command not found. How can I install wifi driver?

I have installed(`iwlwifi-6000g2a-ucode-18.168.6.1.tgz`) from [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html). When I extracted I got it(iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode). What I have to do with it?

Output of `/usr/sbin/modprobe --version` :

```
kmod version 26
+XZ -ZLIB +OPENSSL -EXPERIMENTAL
```

`iwconfig` :

```
root@debian:~# /sbin/iwconfig
enp0s25   no wireless extensions.

wwp0s29u1u4  no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

`lspci -knn | grep -i net -A3` :

```
istiak@debian:~$ lspci -knn | grep -i net -A3
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
        Subsystem: Lenovo 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) (ThinkPad T520) [17aa:21ce]
        Kernel driver in use: e1000e
        Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 04)
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0085] (rev 34)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 AGN [8086:1311]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci -knn |grep -i net -A3`

Comment: @GAD3R Edited...!

Answer (score 0):

The `firmware-iwlwifi` is a non-free software.

You need to add `non-free` to your `sources.list`. See [Example sources.list](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list)

```
sudo sed -i 's/main/& contrib non-free/' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install firmware-iwlwifi
sudo /usr/sbin/modprobe -rv iwlwifi
sudo /usr/sbin/modprobe -v iwlwifi
```

[iwlwifi: Supported Devices](https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi#Supported_Devices)

To solve the command not found error for `ifconfig` and `iwconfig`, you need to install `wireless-tools` and `net-tools`:

```
sudo apt install wireless-tools net-tools
```

Use `/sbin/iwconfig` and `/sbin/ifconfig` because `/sbin` is missing in your root `PATH`.

Comment: I have did this... Do I have to reboot now?

Comment: @Softunes No, it is not Windows. Install the `firmware-iwlwifi`

Comment: How can I install `firmware-iwlwifi`. I never execute `ucode` extension file..! I found `cp iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode /lib/firmware` from readme. I have executed it.. I didn't get any message neither wireless connection.

Comment: @Softunes see my edit, skip the first command because you have already done.

Comment: `E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
` While updating..... `apt install firmware-iwlwifi` successfully unpacked..!

Comment: Done but, no wireless connection..! `apt update` isn't returning any error now..!

Comment: Now, when I tried `/usr/sbin/modprobe -rv iwlwifi`. I got the error `\modprobe: FATAL: Module iwlwifi is in use.`. `-v iwlwifi` isn't returning anything..!

Comment: Okay, but do you realize this command "/usr/sbin/modprobe -rv iwlwifi " is trying to remove the module?  And it can't becuse it's busy -  which impiles it's loaded and should be working. Type "lsmod | grep iwlwifi" to check to see if the module is loaded.